# Create instance of class inside other class

Tags: python

I have to classes like below.

```
class Reports()
_name = 'reports'
def fetch_transaction_invoice():
    #any logic here

 class Bar():
 _name = 'bar'
 def test_method():
     # here i want to access fetch_transaction_invoice of Reports class.
```

but when i try like following

```
class Bar():
 _name = 'bar'
 def test_method():
     Reports.fetch_transaction_invoice ()
```

it gives me error which is following.

```
TypeError: unbound method fetch_transaction_invoice() must be called with Reports instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: You aren't providing `self`. Maybe `fetch_transaction_invoice` should be a static method, or maybe you should have a `Reports` instance, or maybe you should [stop writing classes](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0). It's hard to tell from so little information.

Comment: The method `fetch_transaction_invoice()` isn't static, so you need to call it, e.g. `Reports().fetch_transaction_invoice()`. And the method is missing `self` parameter.

Comment: Irrespective of who voted, the short answer is: no. Longer answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/3001761.

Comment: Given that it demonstrates a complete lack of understanding even the basics of writing a Python class (aside from the syntax errors and indentation errors), I think the down vote is warranted for lack of research.

Comment: I've written psudo code in question and obviously indentation are not very much important in psudo code when you are trying to give an example of what you tried and what is the context.

Comment: Note the requirement for a [mcve], not pseudocode. Context is important. If `fetch_transaction_invoice` doesn't actually need any class or instance state, why is it even in a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works by using the `@classmethod` decorator:

```
 class Reports():
    _name = 'reports'
    @classmethod
    def fetch_transaction_invoice(cls):
        print('fetched')

 class Bar():
    _name = 'bar'
    def test_method(self):
        Reports.fetch_transaction_invoice ()

 Bar().test_method()
```

prints

```
 fetched
```

(I had to make some assumptions about what you were attempting due to some indenting issues.)